# How to Rewrite a Rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iis, isapi-rewrite

I have a few dozen links, that are generating a page not found error because of the parameters in query-string:

```
http://www.domain.com/publication?id=test
http://www.domain.com/publication?id=test&tkn=25MMI7
http://www.domain.com/publication?id=VfgodzE4Akg&tkn=25GJK02&gid=VCsfkQENp4g:20150323:s
```

I want to be able to redirect them to:

```
http://www.domain.com/publication/?id=test
http://www.domain.com/publication/?id=test&tkn=25MMI7
http://www.domain.com/publication/?id=VfgodzE4Akg&tkn=25GJK02&gid=VCsfkQENp4g:20150323:s
```

I have access to the .htaccess file, but I have no experience with the syntax.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the following rewrite rule that looks for anything after the '?' sign:

```
RewriteRule /publication/?\?(.*) /publication/?$1 [NC,L]
```

So far it seems to be working as I needed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the URLs above, try the following rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^publication$ /publication/ [NC,R=301,L]
```